# javascript getElementsByName error for innerHTML

Tags: javascript, dom

I am use DOM to get multiple class names and pass a function(with_value) to access individual elements. However I get a Uncaught TypeError cannot read propperty 'innerHTML' of undefined. 
Code is:

```
<script>
    var token = 1;
                 var x = document.getElementsByName("commpare_name");

                var y = document.getElementsByName("compare_image");

     function add_compare(num)
            {  num=0;



                    var a = x[num].innerHTML.toUpperCase();
                        alert(a);
                    document.getElementById('name1').innerHTML = a;
                    document.getElementById('name1').title = a
                    document.getElementById('pics1').src = x[num].src;
                    a = document.getElementById('view-details0').action;


            }
</script>

<span id="compare_name" name="compare_name" >no1</span>
<form id="view-details0">
<input type="button" value="Add to Compare" onclick="add_compare(1)">
</form> 

<span id="compare_name" name="compare_name" >no1</span>
<form id="view-details0">
<input type="button" value="Add to Compare" onclick="add_compare(2)">
</form>
```

edit:

```
<a class="description" id="name1" href="" target="_blank" title="ADD TO COMPARE" ><span>ADD TO COMPARE</span></a>
```

the innerHTML and thee href of this needs to change

Answer (score 3):

You are giving wrong name in script

```
commpare_name - > compare_name
```

Answer (score 1):

The actual problem is that you execute your JavaScript before the DOM Content is loaded. Wrap your JS in

```
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded',function(){
  …
});
```

or put your `<script>` at the bottom of your `<body>`.

When you execute

```
var x = document.getElementsByName("commpare_name");
```

you get an empty `NodeList` because no elements with such a name exist yet. When you try to access `x[num]` which is `x[0]` that property `0` doesn’t exist, thus it results in `undefined`.

```
var a = x[num].innerHTML.toUpperCase();
```

Afterwards `.innerHTML` is being read from `undefined` which is impossible.

---

**Update:** I didn’t realize that the `name` was misspelt as well as pointed out by [Vivek Gupta](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4558918/vivek-gupta). You obviously have to change that. If your `<script>` actually is above that HTML then you still have to change the script position or wrap it as described above.

Answer (score 0):

```
var x = document.getElementsByName("commpare_name");
```

should be..

```
var x = document.getElementsByName("compare_name");  //Typo in **compare_name**
```